# jquery nextUntil inclusive of the matched elements

Tags: jquery

I have some html, and I wish to wrap some elements with a div.

The final outcome should be that from each `--greystart--` until `--greyend--` will be wrapped in a `div`, including the matched elements themselves.

I've looked atusing `.addBack()` and `.addSelf()` but can't get anything to work correctly. This is what I've managed

```js
if($('.event_description:contains("--greystart--")')) {
  $('p:contains("--greystart--")').each(function(i){
$(this)
  .nextUntil('p:contains("--greyend--")')
  .addBack()
  .wrapAll('<div class="bg--grey" />')
  });
};
```

```css
.bg--grey {background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event_description">
  <p>--greystart--</p>
  <p>saddasdsa</p>
  <p>dsadasdsa</p>
  <p>fdfdfsfds</p>
  <p>dfsdffdsfds</p>
  <p>--greyend--</p>
  <p>dfdsfdsf</p>
  <p>--greystart--</p>
  <p>saddasdsa</p>
  <p>dsadasdsa</p>
  <p>fdfdfsfds</p>
  <p>dfsdffdsfds</p>
  <p>--greyend--</p>
  <p>dfdsf</p>
  <p>--greystart--</p>
  <p>saddasdsa</p>
  <p>dsadasdsa</p>
  <p>fdfdfsfds</p>
  <p>dfsdffdsfds</p>
  <p>--greyend--</p>
  <p>fdfdsdsf</p>
  <p>--greystart--</p>
  <p>saddasdsa</p>
  <p>dsadasdsa</p>
  <p>fdfdfsfds</p>
  <p>dfsdffdsfds</p>
  <p>--greyend--</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the *adjacent sibling selector* to include the `<p>` that is right next to it:

```
.nextUntil('p:contains("--greyend--") + p')
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pncy5ero/1/)

Comment: Ahh this has worked but relied on the next element to always be a `p`. I've modified it for my use by including a wildcard selector instead of the `p`: `.nextUntil('p:contains("--greyend--") + *')`